# Gremlin: Rollback the query if an exception occurs

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to submit a batch like operation for creating multiple vertices and edges in the same query.

```
g.addV('os').property('name', 'linux').as('linux').
  addV('os').property('name', 'windows').as('windows').
  addV('os').property('name', 'mac').as('mac').
  addE('competitor').from('linux').to('UNEXISTING OS').      # fail here
  addE('competitor').from('linux').to('windows').
  addE('competitor').from('windows').to('mac').
  addE('competitor').from('linux').to('mac').
  iterate()
```

The query is constructed to intentionally fail, however all vertices before the failing line are being created.
Is it possible to achieve a kind of transaction for the whole query? So that if one subquery fails, it should rollback the ones that were previously executed.

Thanks!

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) it says: “Neptune opens a new transaction at the beginning of each Gremlin traversal and closes the transaction upon the successful completion of the traversal. The transaction is rolled back when there is an error.” So I would have thought that it would undo the vertex creation.

Comment: @cygri hmm, indeed you are right. I thought that Neptune would consider a transaction a traversal that is separated via `;` . I was trying to execute the query in Gremlin Console, but never tried against Neptune database. Seems that the transaction logic is let to be implemented by providers themselves. Thank you!

Comment: I see. Interesting. If you have a minute, why don't you post that finding as an answer to your own question, so that future visitors can find it easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query could not be executed in the Gremlin Console using TinkerGraph,
as per TinkerPop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/reference/#connecting-gremlin-server-limitations), there isn't support for transactions for built-in TinkerGraph object.

But, as cygri pointed out, AWS Neptune offers support for transactions ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html)), that can be executed under the form of original query from OP or by separating queries by a semicolon (;) or a newline character (\n)

```
g.addV('os').property('name', 'linux').next();
g.addV('os').property('name', 'windows').next();
g.addE('competitor').from('1101').to('1102')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Gremlin Sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-sessions.html); create a sessioned-connection and it'll rollback queries in case of an error.